# Google Sheets - Code to send an email to an address upon dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to set up my dropdown options in Google sheets to trigger email responses after a selection a made from the dropdown. For example, When "Ready For QA" "Error Found or "Approved" is selected in column I from the dropdown, an email should be triggered and sent to the email address in column H that includes Subject line: "Line item is ready for QA" with information from all cells in the row A through P that includes the headers from each column.

Am I missing anything from my code below?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qwyvtSo_mzHztZJ7MJLfPy8TlvPYqCLIEKC9APBWeMQ/edit#gid=78026112

```
var sheetname = "march";
//Installable Trigger 
function sendEmail(e) {
  // Get sheet, row and column where the event was triggered 
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("march");
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  // Check if the event meets your conditions
  if (e.value === "Ready for QA" && col === 9) {
    // Get headers and data where the "Ready for QA" was set
    var headers =  sheet.getRange("A1:P1").getValues()[0];
    var data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 16).getValues()[0];
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: data[7], // user's email Also
      subject: `Line item is ${e.value}`,
      // Combine the right header with the right data and send them as the body
      body: headers.map((el, index) => `${el}: ${data[index]}`).join("\n")
    });
  }
}
```

[image: picture of error message sent to me after selecting Ready for QA in the drop down]

Comment: I cannot open your shared Spreadsheet. So although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, I think that the issue in your script might be `getActiveCell(sheet.getLastRow(), 1)` and `MailApp.sendEmail` is used as the simple trigger. In your case, how about modifying to `getActiveCell()` [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell) and running the script by the installable OnEdit event trigger?

Comment: Hello JBon102, did @Tanaike's suggestion work for your situation? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For sending an email meeting the conditions and the format you want, you  have to set an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) and use this code I prepared:

```
//Installable Trigger 
function sendEmail(e) {
  // Get sheet, row and column where the event was triggered 
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("YOUR-SHEET-NAME");
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  // Check if the event meets your conditions
  if (col === 9) {
    // Get headers and data where the "Ready for QA" was set
    var headers =  sheet.getRange("A1:P1").getValues()[0];
    var data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 16).getValues()[0];
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: data[7], // user's email Also
      subject: `Line item is ${e.value}`,
      // Combine the right header with the right data and send them as the body
      body: headers.map((el, index) => `${el}: ${data[index]}`).join("\n")
    });
  }
}
```

Notice how I used the `e` argument, which is the [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) for the [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) event trigger to get the sheet values. Also, I would recommend you set your column ***Order ID*** format as `Plain text` because Apps Script could take it as a huge number and therefore set it into scientific notation.

Now, for setting up the installable trigger, do the following:

1) Go to your Apps Script project.

2) Click Edit->Current project's triggers.

3) Click "+ Add Trigger".

4) Select :

- Choose which function to run -> *Function Name* (in this case ***sendEmail***).
- Select event source-> From spreadsheet.
- Select event type -> On edit.

Comment: Thanks alberto for the code. Im entered it but im still getting the error message in my inbox that reads "Error Message:TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null".

Comment: ```var sheetname = "Copy of QA Analysis Doc";


function sendEmail(e) {
  
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Copy of QA Analysis Doc");
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();

  if (e.value === "Ready for QA" && col === 9) {
    
    var headers =  sheet.getRange("A1:P1").getValues()[0];
    var data = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 16).getValues()[0];
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: data[7], 
      subject: `Line item is ${e.value}`,
      
      body: headers.map((el, index) => `${el}: ${data[index]}`).join("\n")
    });
  }
}

Comment: on [```getSheetByName("YOUR-SHEET-NAME")```](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) you have to put your own sheet's name, like in this case ***March***

Comment: I updated the sheet name and im still getting this error message when I debug.   "TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined (line 7, file "Code") and here is what I have on line 7.             var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Copy-of-QA-Analysis-Doc");

Comment: Here is the sheet name var sheetname = "Copy-of-QA-Analysis-Doc";

Comment: For what I can see in the spreadsheet you shared, the sheet's name is ***March***, not ***Copy-of-QA-Analysis-Doc***, so you should declare your variable ```sheetname``` as ```March``` or otherwise change your sheet's name to ```Copy-of-QA-Analysis-Doc```.

Comment: Thank you for that, I've made the update to the sheet name and now im gettting error "Function : send email"  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null"

Comment: Please, edit your question with the code you have now. The spreadsheet is still the same from your question?

Comment: Sorry about that as you can tell I'm pretty new to this. I've updated the code above and I also included a picture of the error message I receive in my inbox after selecting Ready for QA in the drop down.

Comment: your sheet's name is ***March***, but in your code is ***march***, without capital ***M***. The names are case sensitive

Comment: Hi Alberto! I made the fix but now i'm getting this message in my inbox "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null"

Comment: You named the Spreadsheet as ***march***, but you let the sheet's name as ***March*** instead of ***march***. I made the changed for you in the Spreadsheet you shared in your question. Please try again and let me know

Comment: Hi Alberto that worked perfect! THANK YOU! but i'm not getting emails when "Error Found" or "Approved" is selected. Can you add that in for me too? Thats the very last piece to this puzzle. I appreciate all of your help on this!

Comment: You're welcome!! I modified my code in the ```if``` statement so it can accept the other values. If my answer helped you, please consider mark it as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)